# Updated versions of FSI courses

Tags: multiple-languages, electronic-resources

The Foreign Service Institute (FSI) courses (found [here](https://fsi-languages.yojik.eu/languages/fsi.html), [here](http://www.101languages.net/fsi-courses/) or [here](https://www.livelingua.com/fsi-language-courses.php)) are **free**, thorough, and an amazing resource for language learners. But they are quite *old* - many of the courses are well over 50 years old, since they were mostly created in the 1960s. That's not to say they aren't useful anymore. They are definitely still useful, but languages change a little with each generation and updated materials are nice to have.

Do you know if this tremendous resource has ever been updated, even if just for certain languages?

Answer (score 5):

It appears that new audio has been recorded for the [Italian Fast course](https://fsi-languages.yojik.eu/languages/oldfsi/languages/italian-fast-updated.html) (by a third party), and there are web versions of a few sections of some of the courses available [here](https://ielanguages.com/fsi.html).

I was not able to find updated versions of the other FSI courses *exactly*, but I was able to find some more programs related to the US government:

- The [Defense Language Institute Foreign Language Center Language Survival Kits](http://fieldsupport.dliflc.edu/productList.aspx?v=language) appear to be little more than phrasebooks, but they may be useful nonetheless. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_Language_Institute):

> The Defense Language Institute (DLI) is a United States Department of Defense (DoD) educational and research institution

- [yojik.eu](https://yojik.eu/) appears to have not only the FSI courses, but some older DLI courses and US Peace-Corps language materials as well (texts/workbooks).
- [DLI Global Language Online Support System (GLOSS)](https://gloss.dliflc.edu/) contains various online, interactive lessons/exercises in many languages, as well as audio recordings.